# Embedded C++ save and restore data

Tags: embedded, data, c++

I am working on an embedded C++ project. I am dealing with complex and dynamic objects with lots of objects pointing to one another. I need to store and recall these objects to non-volatile memory. In the past I used structures for data and could easily turn them into byte streams using tricks like unions. How do I do this with objects?

Comment: Keep in mind that there are a limited number of writes to non-volatile memory, so if you are doing this frequently you could wear out the memory. Other than that this seems like a C++ question in general and not an embedded question specifically.

Comment: Elliot Alderson has an important point. As for how to save objects, you need to take address in memory where the object begins and its size in bytes and manually copy the from RAM (or wherever the object is sitting) byte by byte with a loop. You may want to google things like "memory pointer" "object in memory" and similar things (if you're not familiar yet, that is). It's a little overwhelming at first (actually, it's pretty brain-breaking)

Comment: The problem is converting pointers to other objects to something that is not a pointer but some sort of other reference so that when you load objects to memory again and they are in different memory addresses or in different order you can change them back to memory addresses. If you can do this using C++ on a linux/windows/macos/whatever using files as storage then you can do it in embedded C++ using flash. The embedded context is irrelevant.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is "serialization" and it is not trivial.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a pure software question that belongs on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Tim, you either decide what's necessary in each case to re-construct the object from simple data values and save those data values or else, if your situation means you can bring back the objects from non-volatile storage and place them exactly where they were before, you may learn about the details that your compiler uses in generating C++ object structures and save the entire structure just like you used to do with unions. There's no magic to anything. But people have gravitated away from binary storage to saving only what's needed to re-construct. Your call, though.

Comment: Check the [Factory Method and Factory Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/creational-patterns).

Comment: @DaveTweed This isn't pure software since a PC solution and a microcontroller solution will look very different. There's limited flash, limited RAM and no heap.

Comment: @Lundin: So? Software on a microcontroller is still just software. We entertain questions about embedded programming here on EE.SE, but only if they relate in some way to the hardware design.

Answer (score 2):

I would provide each class with a member function `serialize`, which fills up an internal `static uint8_t` buffer with the variables that need to be stored, then returns a `const uint8_t*` and a size to the caller, who can then pass that along to the NVM driver.

If you have complex inheritance you can let each inherited class append its own data at the end of this buffer.

Similarly, you might want a `deserialize` routine initialized with a pointer to NVM and a size. This might be a constructor even.

Also keep in mind that NVM variables that are changed in run-time need to be accessed through `volatile` qualified variables/pointers.

Comment: You can make serialize and deserialize static functions so that they can create and return a pointer to a new object. For embedded make serialize work like snprintf, which is copyless.

Comment: @Jeroen3 This design assumes a microcontroller system with limited memory and no dynamic allocation. The point is to not allocate big buffers all over the place.

Comment: it's fine to use `new` if you're only going to make the object once.

Answer (score 1):

This process is called "Object serialization". If you have a powerful MCU, you might be able to use an off-the-shelf library to do it.

If not, it shouldn't be too hard for you to write a few functions and methods to accomplish this. Your objects contain data in the form of variables, so all you need to do is read the data in each variable and store it in NVM in an organized way.

When you start back up, you read the data from NVM and use it to create objects.

Pointers would be hard to store this way, but you can do things like create an id for each object, and store the ID of the object you want to point to, instead of the actual memory address.

Dynamic memory allocation also complicates this a bit, but the same basic strategy applies.